# Old UI NGUI Elements

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I download the controller from inter net but its Ui is working with old NGUI methods
this code is getting use for camera rotation and I cant seem to understand this Eventlisteners
can anyone help me to change this awake function new new Ui(canvas) functions.

```
private void Awake()
{
    UIEventListener uIEventListener = rotateAreaBtn;
    uIEventListener.onPress = (UIEventListener.BoolDelegate)Delegate.Combine(uIEventListener.onPress, new UIEventListener.BoolDelegate(OnPressArea));
    UIEventListener uIEventListener2 = rotateAreaBtn;
    uIEventListener2.onDrag = (UIEventListener.VectorDelegate)Delegate.Combine(uIEventListener2.onDrag, new UIEventListener.VectorDelegate(OnDragCam));
}

public void OnDragCam(GameObject obj, Vector2 deta)
{
    dragDeta = deta;
    isDrag = true;
    PlayerController.instance.fireTarget = null;
    if (PlayerController.instance.curState == PLAYERSTATE.FIGHT)
    {
        PlayerController.instance.ChangeState(PLAYERSTATE.NORMAL);
    }
    else if (PlayerController.instance.curState != PLAYERSTATE.CAR && (PlayerController.instance.animaCtl.isAimFlag || PlayerController.instance.animaCtl.needToAimFlag))
    {
        PlayerController.instance.ChangeState(PlayerController.instance.curState);
    }
}

public void OnPressArea(GameObject obj, bool press)
{
    isPress = press;
    if (!press)
    {
        dragDeta = Vector2.zero;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ngui rises my blood. But what exactly dont you get.  Theres a on press and an on drag. They both sound fairly explanatory

Comment: onPress would be replaced by adding a handler for the onClick of the Button.  For drag, look at the IPointer interfaces.

Comment: Man NGUI sucks. I have did it with Event Triggers. Thank you anyways .